# When is _create() method of factory.DjangoModelFactory called when initialising an object?

Tags: django, factory-boy

We are using factoryboy and following the docs seem to do the task intended but am trying to understand what goes behind the screens.

We are overwriting _create() method of factory.DjangoModelFactory for custom user creation. However there is no **init** in the class. How does python ensure that _create() method is called every time a factory object is created?

```
class CustomerFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):

      class Meta:
            model = Customer

      @class_method
       def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
           ...... <custom_code>

alex = CustomerFactory()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory boy uses a metaclass to achieve this result.

Basically, the metaclass ([factory.base.FactoryMetaClass](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/master/factory/base.py#L30)) receives the class definition from your code, and transforms it — just like Django does with its models.
This happens inside [`FactoryMetaClass.__new__`](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/master/factory/base.py#L49).

The metaclass also provides a [custom `__call__` method](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/blob/master/factory/base.py#L33-L47), which is used by Python when you run `CustomerFactory()`.

The call order is then:

1. Your code calls `CustomerFactory()`
2. Python actually runs `FactoryMetaClass.__call__(CustomerFactory)`
3. That function calls `CustomerFactory.create()` (since it's a `DjangoModelFactory`; other factories route the default call to `MyFactory.build()`)
4. FactoryBoy's core engine resolves parameters and declarations
5. And provides the resulting list of parameters to `CustomerFactory._create(**params)`
6. Where your code takes over.

Comment: Am still trying to comprehend how Python executes step2. Any document that will help me understand step 2? Also looking at the code references provided the base class for DjangoModelFactory is base.Factory. How is FactoryMetaClass being called in this process?

Comment: Answering my own question, base.Factory acts as the base class for django.djangoModelFactory due to the lines                                                
    'Factory = FactoryMetaClass(str('Factory'), (BaseFactory,), {
    'Meta': BaseMeta,
    '__doc__': """Factory base with build and create support.
    This class has the ability to support multiple ORMs by using custom creation
    functions.
    """,
})
' and the default behaviour of a MetaClass is as explained correctly in the above answer.